# HowTo convert escaped Unicode String to Unicode Character

Tags: swift3

I have a plist which looks like this in a text editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <string>\u{1f604}</string>  
        <string>7\u{20e3}</string>  
        <string>\u{1f1ef}\u{1f1f5}</string> 
        ...     
    </array>
</plist>
```

When I get and print the string, it prints like this:

```
\u{1f604}
```

I suspect the string is somehow invisibly escaped as `\\u{1f604}`.

How can I convert the string, so it prints the represented character ?

Comment: Did you post a comment to my answer, and then removed it? I recall reading it and I was about to get back to it, but it isn't there.

Comment: Yes. I did. I was mentioning an issue, which I than found out is also handled by the accepted answer. That's why I removed the comment and accepted the working answer. Sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that plist editor of Xcode can contain emojis directly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>emojis</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
        <string></string>
        <string>&#x1F601;</string><!-- or you can use numeric reference of XML, in XML editor -->
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But, if you already have some escaped version of plist file, you may need to convert it. Using `NSRegularExpression`, you can write something like this:

```
class EscapedUnicodeConverter: NSRegularExpression {
    override func replacementString(for result: NSTextCheckingResult, in string: String, offset: Int, template templ: String) -> String {
        if
            result.numberOfRanges == 2,
            case let nsString = string as NSString,
            case let matchedString = nsString.substring(with: result.rangeAt(1)),
            let unicodeScalarValue = UInt32(matchedString, radix: 16),
            let unicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(unicodeScalarValue)
        {
            return String(unicodeScalar)
        } else {
            return super.replacementString(for: result, in: string, offset: offset, template: templ)
        }
    }
}
//Using pattern for Swift
let unicodeConverterForSwift = try! EscapedUnicodeConverter(pattern: "\\\\u\\{([0-9A-Fa-f]+)\\}")

let origStr = "\\u{1f600}"
let result = unicodeConverterForSwift.stringByReplacingMatches(in: origStr, range: NSRange(0..<origStr.utf16.count), withTemplate: "???")
print(result) //->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to parse the string manually:

```
func toCharacter(_ string: String) -> Character? {
    guard
        let start = string.characters.index(of: "{"),
        let end = string.characters.index(of: "}"),
        start < end
        else { return nil }

    let range = string.index(after: start) ..< end

    guard
        let number = Int(string[range], radix: 16),
        let scalar = UnicodeScalar(number)
        else { return nil }

    return Character(scalar)
}

toCharacter("\\u{1f604}") // ""
```